# Which one is better std::prev(itr) or --itr?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I am iterating through a bidirectional data structure. I can do it either by using (`++` , `--`) or (`std::prev`,`std::next`,`std::advance`). Is there a advantage of using later over the other?

Comment: please be more specific: what exactly is the container/ the iterator?

Comment: @Sumit Jha Sometimes they are not interchangeable. For example compare auto next = std::next( first ); and auto next = ++first;

Comment: The main thing is that they are not equivalent. But that said `std::prev` will do evil things to a container that doesn't naturally allow iteration in that direction, `--itr` on such a container will not compile. So I'd use the latter.

Comment: @Bathsheba Wouldn't `std::prev` use `operator--` under the hoods, too, and thus fail to compile as well, if the iterator is not a bidirectional one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They slightly do different things. So neither is better in general.

In particular `std::prev` doesn't modify `itr`. So, it is better when `itr` shouldn't or couldn't (see S.M.'s answer for example of latter) be modified. `--itr` and `std::advance` do modify `itr`, so they are better when `itr` must be modified.

An advantage of `std::prev` and `std::advance` over `--itr` is their argument `n` which allows avoiding writing a loop when you need to advance multiple steps. They're more efficient than a loop if the iterator is random access.

Comment: If iterator is random access, we could do `i + n` and `i += n` as well...

Comment: @Aconcagua and the (possibly dis-) advantage of using `std::prev / std::advance` over `-` / `-=` is that it works on any type of bidirectional iterator; not just random access.

Comment: @Aconcagua I forgot to add in my last comment that indeed, looping with `--` also works for non-random-access iterators.

Comment: Well, I do not disagree with you apart from the last sentence of your answer... Although technically not wrong, with RA iterators I would simply not loop, but use +/-(=) n operators instead. `std::advance`'s main benefit is not having to write the loop explicitly with NRA iterators... "Consistency" then could be the argument to use it on RA iterators as well.

Comment: @Aconcagua quite often I want my algorithms to work with NRA iterators, but I also want advancing to be efficient with RA iterators. `std::prev` and `std::advance` achieve both of those goals. +/-(=) operators do not achieve both.

Comment: There is no difference in efficiency: NRA: have a loop, use increment/decrement; RA: use direct offset. The advantage of `std::advance` is hiding this difference away (and saving the explicit loop in the former case).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168658/discussion-between-aconcagua-and-user2079303).

Answer (score 4):

I assume the advantages are good described in [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/). For example `std::prev` has the advantage described below:

> Although the expression `--c.end()` often compiles, it is not guaranteed
>   to do so: `c.end()` is an rvalue expression, and there is no iterator
>   requirement that specifies that decrement of an rvalue is guaranteed
>   to work. In particular, when iterators are implemented as pointers,
>   `--c.end()` does not compile, while `std::prev(c.end())` does.